# Pagination in flutter with filter implementation

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, filtering

I am using below code for fetching the documents from `Firestore` database in `Flutter Application`, which using using the category filter for the query to retrieve the documents from the database. It is working fine. Now All I need to implement is the pagination in this case, I have checked several examples but not able to find one for this kind of use case.
Though I am able to implement the pagination for the list where there is no filter implementation.

How should I do it in this case?

```
Query query;
    if (category != null){
      query = widget._firestore.collection("items").where("itemCategory", isEqualTo: category ).orderBy("timestamp", descending: true);
    }
    else {
       query = widget._firestore.collection("items").orderBy(
          "timestamp", descending: true);
    }

//inside scaffold
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: query.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

              if (!snapshot.hasData){
                return SliverFillRemaining(

                );
              }
              return SliverList(
                  delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (context, index) {


                          String itemTitle = snapshot.data.documents[index]['itemTitle'];


          return  CardItem(itemTitle:itemTitle                     
                    },
                    childCount:
                    snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.documents.length : 0,
                  ));
            },
          ),
```

Comment: you can achieve pagination using `firestore`. Follow this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors , and there is an useful video on same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU

Comment: @SriDattaYalla I have done this kind of thing , but I am looking for pagination where the category filter for the list is there